# entity framework 3.5 and stored procedure result mapping

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity

Using EF3.5 with Visual Studio 2010 (cannot upgrade to EF4 at this point - don't ask!).

Wanting to create a stored procedure that aggregates some fields from some related tables and materialize the result of the stored procedure as a custom "entity".  This custom entity would be "read only".  I set up the custom entity, the stored procedure, and function import.  When I build my Entity project, I get the following:

> Error 35  Error 3027:
>   No mapping specified for the following
>   EntitySet/AssociationSet -
>   MyCustomEntitySet

It looks like it wants a table mapping defined for my custom entity, however, I would not have one in this case since it aggregates the data over several tables (and filters out some unneccessary data).

Is it possible to map a custom entity to a stored procedure?  Is it possible to do so in a way where the "Update Model From Database" functionality will not break the custom entity or stored proc/function import mapping?

TIA!

Answer (score 3):

We used to get around this by creating a view in the db - the view never actually gets used if you map to stored procedures but it does enable auto-creation of the correct mappings in the entity.

Typically for fairly straight forward procs you can copy/paste the sql to generate the view too - saves some time.

Comment: Yes, this is the workaround we've been using too up to this point.  Wondering if there isn't something more "supported".  For example, this looked promising, however, I could not get it working for me: http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/mapping-stored-procedure

Comment: We went down the hacking the xml file before we went to views, it was a nightmare because things kept getting deleted when we wanted to update from the db so we switched to views. All I can say is good luck and move to EF4 asap it's much much easier to work with.

Comment: In the article I mention above, I get errors when trying to define a <DefiningQuery> element within an <EntitySet>.  However, this seems to indicate it's valid: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738450(v=VS.90).aspx.  I'll likely go the "View"-based approach as well.